# Docker stop says container doesn't exist but docker start does

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have a docker container tagged `ppe`

`sudo docker start ppe` works
But while it's running or not, `sudo docker stop ppe` returns error: `Error response from daemon: No such container: ppe`

Why is it doing that? I literally have to reboot just to stop the container right now

Running Ubuntu server 19.10

**EDIT** Docker ps also shows no containers

Comment: Why do you think the container is running after you started it? Maybe it fails or it just runs one command and then stops? Try `docker ps -a` to see all containers including stopped ones.

Comment: @pLumo because it produces A LOT of debug output on screen